Method for exporting a page from an Electron app?
In Chrome/(most other modern browsers), you can right-click anywhere on a page and click Save as.. to export a page with all resources. This will also save it as the page is currently displayed, not only the original HTML.
I'm using an Electron application and would like to do the same, but the right-click context menu lacks the option. Apart from manually extracting from sources, how else can I do something similar to the Save as.. option? I've tried some JavaScript code to output to a file but it doesn't seem to work. I have to do this via the DevTools console.

Assuming your electron renderer window is called "win", you can do win.webContents.savePage('path/to/file', 'HTMLComplete')
The second parameter is the save type which could be one of the following

HTMLOnly - Save only the HTML of the page.
HTMLComplete - Save complete-html page.
MHTML - Save complete-html page as MHTML.

See more about this here

Thanks for the resource, but does this work if I only have access to the developer tools console? (ie I don't do it via code)

It doesn't seem to work client-side, const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron') causes Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.

@ItsCube This code is to be used in your main file, if you want to have it through a context menu (right-click) then you'll need to add a custom context menu through something like electron-context-menu > https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-context-menu
then on click event add the code I mentioned in my answer

thanks for your explanation, I thought that it could be done in the DevTools console.
